# No Disk Utility

Tags: settings, disk-management

I get that you made it small, clean, and simple. But why would you not include a disk utility already incorporated? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. It is missing by default, you aren't missing anything. But why its is not added has to be answered by the team. I am just a user.

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered question yourself. It's simple, it's elementary, not everyone needs it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Just add Gnome Disks from the app center.  Done.

It is an interesting question though.  Isn't GParted on the live disk?

Comment: I know how to get one. Just found it odd as every other system I have tried always has one. And I had to download granted but it's in the app store.